# SQL conditional select for value in the same table group

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

We have a table like this:

```
id  mid mult    tr  result
----------------------------
1   1   1,35    0   1   
2   1   5,85    0   2   
3   1   4       1   X   
50  2   1,3     1   1   
51  2   7       0   2   
52  2   4       0   X   
99  3   2,45    0   1   
100 3   2,2     0   2   
101 3   3,3     1   X   
105 4   2,3     0   1   
106 4   2,4     0   2   
107 4   3,2     1   X   
111 5   3       1   1   
112 5   1,9     0   2   
113 5   3,25    0   X
```

What we need is a query that will bring us a table which will count how many times before, for a specific mid(match), have the same mults(multipliers) for result = 1 and result = x have occurred and group them so that we can count them. Something like

```
select mult(where result = 1), mult(where result = x), count(1)
```

The result will be like this

```
mult_1      mult_x      count
------------------------------
1,35        4           33
1,3         4           112
```

The above states that we have seen 33 matches where the mult for result = 1 was 1,35 AND mult for result = x was 4. Also, we found 112 matches where multi for result = 1 was 1,3 AND for result = x mult was 4 (results are not dependant on the first table).

I find it rather complex myself, but hopefully I made sense. I use SQL Server 2008, so any method is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my (final) solution in action: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a516/7

There are a number of assumptions I'm making here.

- I'm assuming that every `mid` value is going to have at most 1 `result` value of `'1'` and 1 result of `'2'`.
- I'm assuming that if you want to specify a mid and have the query run off of that.

  - This assumption turned out to be wrong.
- I'm assuming that you want to include the data for the `mid` you specify.

  - This assumption turned out to be wrong, it was every match.
- I'm assuming that you want to include every `mid` (or match) before the `mid` you specify.

  - This assumption turned out to be wrong, it was every match.
- I'm assuming that for any mult_1 and mult_x combination you find in this way, you want the count of how many times that combination occurs, even if it occurs after the match(`mid`) that  you specified.

  - This assumption turned out to be wrong, it was just for every match.

If all of these assumptions sound right, then this might create the result you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @Mid INT = 2

;WITH MatchResults AS
(
  SELECT
    Mid
    , [1] AS MultWithResult1
    , [X] AS MultWithResultX
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Mid
      , mult
      , result
    FROM Matches
    WHERE result IN ('1', 'X')
  ) Base
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(mult)
    FOR result
    IN
    (
      [1]
      , [X]
    )
  ) Pivoted
)
SELECT
  mult.MultWithResult1 AS mult_1
  , mult.MultWithResultX AS mult_x
  , COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM MatchResults mult
GROUP BY mult.MultWithResult1
  , mult.MultWithResultX
```

EDIT: I have edited it based on the response to my answer to what I think he means.

Comment: that is very close to what  we want. The only thing is that if I add 3 extra rows in the table, say
 `(156, 14, '1,35', '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '1'),
 (157, 14, '5,85', '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2'),
 (158, 14, '4', '2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'X');`
which is the same as the 1st only with different mid's it should return a count of 2 (since 2 different mid's were found with the same mults for x and 1 )

Comment: @kamperone I had to guess at what your criteria was because you haven't stated it in a way that I can understand. This is how I would state your goal, so if you can correct this I'll fix the query to do what you want: Given a match ID(`mid`) you want to find the `mult` for `result='1'` and the `mult` for `result='X'` for that match, and every match with a lower `mid` value, and then get the `COUNT(*)` of how many times those combinations of `mult_1` and `mult_x` occur on the table for any given `mid`.

Comment: @kamperone: I edited my answer to reflect the stated goal in my last comment. If that's not accurate, please let me know.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Jeremy. Your solution is exactly what I wanted! The only thing I changed was the limit by 2 you set, since I want results for the whole table and not only for two rows. That won't create a proble, right? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you didn't want to specify anything with a match and just wanted the counts for the whole table of every combination. That makes SO much more sense. In your question you said "for a specific match(mid)" so I was trying to figure out how you wanted to limit. I get it now. I'll update my answer to reflect that and not waste time spent doing another CTE and join it was only doing to limit what you didn't need to limit.

Comment: Jeremy I was wondering if you were willing to help me a bit more. It's the same code you suggested, but there's a new column named `true` and it's a boolean so all fields are either 1 or 0. Next to the `count` column I'd like to have a `true` column that for every combination, it will count how many times this was true. The only thing is that I actually tried thid and I got different results with a lot of `null` cells all over my results.

Comment: @kamperone I'm going to bed now, but just as a note, I'll leave this up and get you an answer tomorrow. :)

Comment: @kamperone I don't fully understand what you mean. The tr column has a true (1) for every mid at least once. I don't know what it represents so I have a hard time understanding what the logic is for setting it true. I"m giving you, the combination of the mult value for a mid where result = '1' and the same where result = 'X'. `tr` in your example data is always true for either the 1 or the X row. What exactly are you trying to count?

Comment: I realised that my thinking was all wrong. I got it straight now. So, thanks again for your help @Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
select mult_1, mult_x, count() as count
from Matches M
inner join (select distinct M1.mult as mult_1, MX.mult as mult_x from 
           matches as M1, matches as MX
           where M1.result=1 and MX.result=x) M1x
  on (M.mult=M1x.mult_1 and M.result=1) or (M.mult=M1x.mult_x and result=x)
group by mult_1, mult_x
```

EDIT:
I'm supposing you wnat to get the count of all possible combinations of multipliers of matches with result=1 and matches with result = x.

If this is the case, M1x gives all this possible combinations. And you join all the possible matchea with have any of those combinations, and count them, grouping by the possible set of combinations defined by M1x.

Comment: I really don't know if your x is a parameter, or a fixed value x (is that a char column)? So I can't be more precise in my answer. But this is the basic idea of what you have to do. neither I know which are the possible combinations of mult_1 and mult_x.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply JotaBe. With mult_1 and mult_x what I really mean is the mult value when result = x and result = 1 consequently. It's still not possible for me to get these values.

Comment: I still can't understand. Are 1,x,2 the only possible values for result?

Comment: Please, if it was about football bets, look at this which can be the final solution.

Comment: Yes 1,x,2 are the only possible results. Jeremy below got a good grasp on the problem. The only thing is the count of  the occurences.